# Why doesn't NetTrain use GPU as TargetDevice?

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

I have a `NetTrain` call with the following parameters:

```
tNet = NetTrain[inVecs -> outVecs, TargetDevice -> "GPU"];
```

But for some reason, the training is still occurring on the CPU rather than the GPU. I also tried `TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 1}`, matching the GPU number of the NVIDIA card on my computer. But that did not help either.

[image]

Comment: Can you use CUDA? What is the result of ``<< CUDALink`; CUDAQ[]``
For me, training on GPU works and I see a clear difference in CPU usage.

Comment: @halirutan sorry for the long delay. The output of `CUDAQ[]` is `True`. And the output of `CUDADriverVersion[]` is `416.3`, which is the latest driver for the NVIDIA Quadro M1000M chip.

Comment: The windows resource monitor can be deceptive. Click the GPU you want to monitor, and change the graph to compute 0 or 1. You'll then see the proper utilization.

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you run the example n = 100; trainingData = RandomReal[1, {n, 4}] -> RandomReal[1, {n, 4}]; net = NetChain[{8, Tanh, 2048, Tanh, 2048, Tanh, 4}]; trained = NetTrain[net, trainingData, TargetDevice -> "GPU"] I have a Nvidia M1000M with driver 391.03 on windows 10 (1607) and Intel graphics 530 in a HP ZBook g3.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I still see a spike in CPU usage, but not in GPU usage.

Comment: I did that. Unfortunately, I do not see a corresponding spike in GPU usage.